# assertTrue and assertFalse in same JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, junit4, assert

This is my 1st post!

I would like to use both `assertTrue(boolean)` and `assertFalse(boolean)` in the same test  using JUnit4. I am using Parameterization, so I would like to include parameters that will fail the test, to verify that they do infact fail.

The method that I am testing accepts a String, checks if the string is in an acceptable currency format (numbers only, no letters, max 2 digits after a decimal point), and returns a HashMap with 2 keys: VALID which is a boolean denoting the strings validity as a currency, and FORMATTING which is a String added to the original valid String to ensure all valid Strings end up with a decimal point and exactly 2 digits thereafter. Invalid strings will not be formatted.

Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class CheckCurrencyFormatTest {

private String input;
private String output;

@Parameters
 public static Collection<String[]> data() {
   String[][] data = {
        {"1", "1.00"}               //return true
        ,{"1.", "1.00"}             //return true
        ,{"1.0", "1.00"}            //return true
        ,{"1.00", "1.00"}           //return true
        //,{"1.000", "1.000"}         //return false
        //,{"m","m"}                  //return false
    };
   return Arrays.asList(data);
 }

public CheckCurrencyFormatTest( String input, String output) {
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
}

@Test
public void testCheckString() {
    CheckCurrencyFormat ccf = new CheckCurrencyFormat();
    HashMap hm;
    boolean valid;
    String resultString;

    valid = false;
    resultString = "";
    hm = ccf.checkString(input);
    for (Object key : hm.keySet()) {
        if ("VALID".equals(key.toString())){
            valid = Boolean.parseBoolean(hm.get(key).toString());
        }
        if ("FORMATTING".equals(key.toString())){
            System.out.println(input + " and add " + hm.get(key).toString());
            resultString = input+(hm.get(key).toString());
        }
    }
    assertTrue(valid);
    //assertFalse(valid);
    assertEquals(output, resultString);
}
```

The tests run successfully with the following lines commented out: `,{"1.000", "1.000"}`and `,{"m","m"}` and `assertFalse(valid);`

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an "expected result" field

```
private String input;
private String output;
private boolean expectedResult;

@Parameters
 public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
   Object[][] data = {
        {"1", "1.00", true}               //return true
       ,{"1.", "1.00", true}             //return true
        ,{"1.0", "1.00", true}            //return true
        ,{"1.00", "1.00", true}           //return true
        ,{"1.000", "1.000", false}         //return false
        ,{"m","m", false}                  //return false
    };
   return Arrays.asList(data);
 }
```

And in the test method :

```
assertTrue(valid == expectedResult);
```

Comment: this is perfect...almost. `data` is a String array. `true` and `false` don't cut it. `"true"` and `"false"` are ok, along with `assertTrue(valid==Boolean.parseBoolean(expectedResult));`. Thanks a mil

Comment: @user2313901 `data` should be an `Object[]`. JUnit can handle the casts if your constructor takes `(String, String, boolean)`